# Using electron+react.js, components are not rendered in production version

Tags: reactjs, electron, antd, electron-builder

Hi guys new to electron and react.js here. I am writing a NavBar component using antd, everything works fine in dev mode, but nothing is rendered in the production version, it's just all black(i used antd dark theme). any hints will be appreciated!

This is my electron.js file:

```
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 680 ,webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true}});
    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/parts/NavBar'

function App() {

    console.log();
    return (
        <div> 
            <NavBar />
        </div>

    );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb } from 'antd';
import {
    DesktopOutlined,
    PieChartOutlined,
    FileOutlined,
    TeamOutlined,
    UserOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Tasks from '../sections/Tasks';
import Dashboard from '../sections/Dashboard';
import Profiles from '../sections/Profiles';
import Utilities from '../sections/Utilities';
import Settings from '../sections/Settings';


const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;
const version = "v0.0.1";
class NavBar extends Component {
    state = {
        collapsed: false,
    };

    onCollapse = collapsed => {
        console.log(collapsed);
        this.setState({ collapsed });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>

                <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
                    <Sider collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed} onCollapse={this.onCollapse}>
                        <div className="logo" />
                        <div>
                            <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline">
                                <Menu.Item key="1">
                                    <PieChartOutlined />
                                    <span>Option 1</span>
                                    <Link to="/" />
                                </Menu.Item>

                                <Menu.Item key="2">
                                    <DesktopOutlined />
                                    <span>Option 2</span>
                                    <Link to="/tasks" />
                                </Menu.Item>

                                <Menu.Item key="3">
                                    <FileOutlined />
                                    <span>Option 2</span>
                                    <Link to="/profiles" />
                                </Menu.Item>                        

                                <Menu.Item key="4">
                                    <FileOutlined />
                                    <span>Option 2</span>
                                    <Link to="/utilities" />
                                </Menu.Item>

                                <Menu.Item key="5">
                                    <FileOutlined />
                                    <span>Option 2</span>
                                    <Link to="/settings" />
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu>
                        </div>
                    </Sider>



                    <Layout className="site-layout">
                        <Header className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 0 }} />
                        <Content style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                            <Route path="/tasks" component={Tasks} />
                            <Route path="/profiles" component={Profiles} />
                            <Route path="/utilities" component={Utilities} />
                            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
                        </Content>
                        <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{version}</Footer>
                    </Layout>
                </Layout>
            </Router>

        );
    }
}

export default NavBar
```

those menu items all looks the same:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;


class Utilities extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Utilities!!!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Utilities;
```

App.css :

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.dark.css';

.App {
  text-align: left;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <div>
            <App />
        </div>
    </React.StrictMode>,

    document.getElementById('root')
)
    ;

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

.webpack.config.js(in my-project/, outside of src/):

```
// define child rescript
module.exports = config => {
    config.target = 'electron-renderer';
    return config;
}
```

.rescriptsrc.js(in my-project/, outside of src/):

```
module.exports = [require.resolve('./.webpack.config.js')]
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you are using webpack and antd doesn't get bundled because of wrong configurations.

You can use openDevTools to debug this and check for error messages.

```
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
```

Are you using webpack, if you do please post your config files.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying! I have added the config file.